Computer constantly freezing, shutting off, boot looping, etc
It comes and goes, occasionally I'll go a month or two without any issue.
There were no hardware changes that first started this happening, my computer just began freezing completely independent of whatever I'm doing - gaming, watching youtube, idle, etc. When it freezes, there is absolutely no way to get it back without hard rebooting, and if I leave it frozen for a while, the fans will get incredibly loud until I do the reboot.
The single time I've been able to recover without a hard restart after the computer froze was unplugging the HDMI cable (connected to my secondary monitor) from my GPU, plugging it into the motherboard's HDMI port (it didn't come on), and then plugging it back into the GPU's HDMI port.
On top of freezing, it will occasionally instantly shut off with no warning. When either of these things happen, it's anybody's guess if it will struggle to boot again - most often it will. It starts to boot, the lights come on internally, and then it'll randomly shut off again, and continue trying this cycle until it works. During this time, the fan lights and whatever other lights inside go on and off sporadically.
I initially thought it was PSU related, so I got a new one - same problem. I have tried memtest, during which the computer froze about 4 hours in (32gb ram) and never recovered (it showed 0 errors at the time of freezing for what its worth), so I pulled out two of the memory sticks in hopes they were the problem - but it changed nothing.
PCPartPicker Part List: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/3Jq4QP

CPU: Intel Core i5-8600K 3.6 GHz 6-Core Processor  ($205.00 @ Amazon)
CPU Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO 82.9 CFM Sleeve Bearing CPU Cooler
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z370 AORUS Gaming 3 (rev. 1.0) ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws V 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-2400 CL15 Memory
Memory: Patriot Viper 4 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16 Memory
Storage (OS): Samsung 860 Evo 500 GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
Storage: Samsung 860 Evo 500 GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
Storage: Western Digital Caviar Blue 1 TB 3.5" 7200 RPM Internal Hard Drive
Video Card: Gigabyte GAMING OC GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER 8 GB Video Card
Case: Phanteks Enthoo Pro ATX Full Tower Case
Power Supply: Corsair RM850x (2021) 850 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully
Modular ATX Power Supply
Monitor (Primary/DP): Dell S2716DG 27.0" 2560 x 1440 144 Hz Monitor
Monitor (Secondary/HDMI): Asus VS248H-P 24.0" 1920 x 1080 Monitor

Windows 11 Education installed on one of the SSDs.
Here are my event viewer logs from an hour when it occurred, let me know if a broader time range would be more useful.
Here's a video of the boot loop.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

If you can, create a USB stick with a live Linux environment on it and see if it has the same problem. At least it will rule out a problem with your current OS install.  To possibly further determine the problem, it will depend on how far you're willing to do things yourself. You can run from USB and disconnect all your storage. Run without the discrete graphics card, ...

out of curiosity, does the numlock light on the keyboard go on/off if you hit the key while its frozen?

@Silbee Well I went a bit further with this - I completely wiped my SSD and reinstalled windows 11 pro from scratch, and the computer worked perfectly for about 8 hours straight. And then it froze again. My event viewer logs are completely empty at the time the freeze happened, and when I hard shut down the system and restarted it, it went into a boot loop again. I tried changed the graphics card to a new PCIE slot, but it did not affect anything.

@FrankThomas Unfortuantely I'm using a custom keyboard with no num lock specifically - but when it froze about 20 minutes ago, I did test the keyboard and all of the lighting was working while the screen was frozen. I was in a discord call at the time and no audio was coming or going, the system completely froze.

You could try running without the discrete graphics card. The only way i see you solving this is by elimination. I'd start from 1 ssd, 1 RAM stick, 1 monitor and it least try to have it run memtest for a good few hours without locking up.

note that if your keyboard toggle lights come on or go off, then the system is not entirely locked at the kernel. keyboard mode indicators (caps/scroll/num lock) require a software state change (so some CPU is required via IRQ and a DPC call). not sure if you are referring to other backlighting which may not indicate the same.

@Silbee so, Ive since tested it with just one monitor, the graphics card completely removed from the system, and one ram stick - and still the computer randomly shut off while playing stardew valley, a pretty low resource game. However - instead of freezing or instantly shutting the entire computer off, it seemed to just freeze + make my display go black... maybe the graphics card being installed allowed the screen to stay "on/frozen"? This would point to CPU/mobo, possibly? That'd be the best news honestly!

@FrankThomas that makes sense, the lighting i was referring to was just backlighting, so this keyboard doesn't seem like a great indicator there!

@Runni, Thanks for the update! I'd steer towards a motherboard issue but only because from my own experience they fail considerably more than CPU's.  Will be impossible to determine which one without a compatible CPU or motherboard to test with. Sorry i wasnt able to do more then give a few suggestions, but you seem to be doing a great job zooming in on the actual problem. Good luck, i hope you pinpoint the exact culprit !
